# Outputting CSV to String/Table

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV with data that is to be emailed to me at the end of a powershell script. I know that I can attach the CSV file to the email itself, but I'd like to know how to output the data from the CSV straight into the body, formatted properly. I assume that this would involve converting the CSV to a String or something.

I've tried things like `ConvertTo-Csv` along with `Format-Table`, but this comes up without formatting. I've thought of looping through the csv line-by-line but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: What do you mean by "formatting"? Once you convert to CSV string you will lose any formatting. You will need to loop through the data, then format with inline styles an HTML table

Comment: `Import-Csv |Format-Table |Out-String`

Comment: @VinnieJames By formatting, I mean keeping the shape of a table (like the CSV). If I had an HTML table, how would I pass the HTML in an email?

Comment: CSV does not have formatting data, it is a string of Comma Separated Values. Excel auto formats it for you, this may help https://bl.ocks.org/ndarville/7075823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ConvertTo-Html`

```
$body = $YOUR_CSV_DATA | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

Send-MailMessage -To 'abc@example.com' -From 'admin@example.com' -Subject 'Your report' -BodyAsHtml -Body $body -SmtpServer 'smtp.example.com'
```